# Accessing a factory service after a promise is returned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I am building an AngularJS app and have built services that perform ajax requests. Through promises they return once these requests are fulfilled to get the data needed for my view.

using $.Deferred().then() I can wait until my request is complete before executing further code on the controller however I have an issue regarding scoping.

I want to perform a second request which needs to use some of the data collected from the first and therefore must wait for it's promise to be fulfilled before calling the service a second time.

The problem is I can't access my factory service in the promises .then() function despite correctly injecting it into the controller. How can I make the factory available in this promise return so I can call it a second time in this way?

My view controller functions:

```
function getCategories() {
        datacontext.getCategories()
            .then(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    vm.categories = data;
                    categoriesPromise.resolve(data);
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Error obtaining data.');
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                common.logger.log('error', 'Error obtaining the categories.', error, controllerId);
            })
    }

    function getUsers() {

        // Wait until the categories are loaded
        categoriesPromise.then(function (categories) {
            // I want to use dataContext again here
        })
    }
```

I want to use the datacontext used in getCategories again in the categoriesPromise.then() within getUsers().

Comment: TLDR; some code will help us

Comment: Added my view controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Create your factory in this way:

```
 .factory("MyFactory", ['$q', function ($q) {
             return {
                get: function (_tagName) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http.get(_tagName, function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            return deferred.reject(err);
                        } else if (result) {
                            return deferred.resolve(result);
                        }
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
}
}])
```

Then Inject it into your controller:

```
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','MyFactory',
      function ($scope, MyFactory) {

    $scope,getData = function(){

    var success=function(data){
        console.log("Data return successfully", data);
    },error = function(err){
         console.log("something went wrong", err)
     }

  MyFactory.get("tagName").then(success,error)
};
}]);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I have it injected like `angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$rootScope', '$location', 'common', 'datacontext', 'spContext', 'userContext', categories]);` and it still cant be accessed.

Comment: and then in the controller like `function categories($rootScope, $location, common, datacontext, spContext, userContext) {`